# Regex Find the File name without extension including the exceptions such as tar.gz

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse the file name from an URL (e.g. .tar.gz or .zip). For example,

```
*URL:* https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/51/f3afa784d73d1f35dce99f6138eaa779e2098a8dde4e7085ecf6295254bb/google-cloud-storage-1.13.0.tar.gz

*Desired Output:* google-cloud-storage-1.13.0

*URL:* https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/51/f3afa784d73d1f35dce99f6138eaa779e2098a8dde4e7085ecf6295254bb/google-cloud-storage-1.13.0.zip

*Desired Output:* google-cloud-storage-1.13.0
```

So far, with Javascript I have the following:

```
tar_name = url.split('/').pop().replace(/\..+$/, '');
```

Which does not work when filename has dots in it.

Any help regarding how to get the file name from such an url with javascript is well appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to be specific and replace the part ending on `.tar.gz` or `.zip` with an empty string.

```
(?:\.tar\.gz|\.zip)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2KHg2/1)

```js
["https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/51/f3afa784d73d1f35dce99f6138eaa779e2098a8dde4e7085ecf6295254bb/google-cloud-storage-1.13.0.tar.gz",
  "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/51/f3afa784d73d1f35dce99f6138eaa779e2098a8dde4e7085ecf6295254bb/google-cloud-storage-1.13.0.zip"
].forEach(url => {
  url = url.split('/').pop().replace(/(?:\.tar\.gz|\.zip)$/, '');
  console.log(url);
});
```

Or you could for example capture the digits separated by dots at the end and match the chars a-z that follow keeping group 1 in the replacement.

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\.[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OV10Df/1)

```js
["https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/51/f3afa784d73d1f35dce99f6138eaa779e2098a8dde4e7085ecf6295254bb/google-cloud-storage-1.13.0.tar.gz",
  "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/51/f3afa784d73d1f35dce99f6138eaa779e2098a8dde4e7085ecf6295254bb/google-cloud-storage-1.13.0.zip"
].forEach(url => {
  url = url.split('/').pop().replace(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\.[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*$/, "$1");
  console.log(url);
});
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The `\K` is not supported in Javascript. I think If you want to use lookarounds, you might use `^https:\/\/.*\/\K.*?(?=(?:\.[a-z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*)$)` and get the match. In Javascript, you could get group 1 `^https:\/\/.*\/(.*?)(?=(?:\.[a-z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*)$)` https://regex101.com/r/kEhfnw/1 The second `.*` could be non greedy or else it will first match until the end of the string and then backtracks to fulfill the assertion which will be true after it encounters the first `\.[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: Thank you for letting know, I thought you are away so deleted that comment, Thanks a TON for guiding here, cheers :)